# C# ContextMenu EventArgs

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, contextmenu

when building a click event method for a context menu, what does the `Event Args` pass on a click event?

I'm trying to build a context menu for a Tree-list so that when i right click on a folder i have the option to create a new folder.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to pass the folder that was clicked on so that i can create the folder in the correct location.

this is what I have so far:

```
    private void qList_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();

            //folder or file
            if(e.Node.ImageKey == "folder")
            {
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Create New Folder",CreateNewFolder_Click));
                cm.MenuItems.Add("Create New QPack");
                cm.MenuItems.Add("Remove New Folder");
                e.Node.ContextMenu = cm;
            }
            else if (e.Node.ImageKey == "files")
            {
                cm.MenuItems.Add("Create QPack", CreateNewQPack_Click);
                cm.MenuItems.Add("Remove QPack");
                e.Node.ContextMenu = cm; 
            }

        }
    }

    private void CreateNewFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void CreateNewQPack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: " how to pass the folder that was clicked" - what do you mean by it? Can you clarify a bit? You have `e.Node` that is your clicked tree node, using its [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) property you can [traverse the tree to restore the file's system path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569850/get-current-directory-of-selected-treeview-in-c-sharp). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: so you're essentially saying forget trying to pass it through an arg and just use treelist.SelectedNode

Comment: I was originally just confused about whet exactly the EventArgs passes on a click event, but the suggestion also works, thank you

Comment: TreeView is not the file system representation tool - it is view control for hierarchical data. It does not give any additional information to the OnClick event. You have to restore the hierarchy manually. Well, you can raise some another event that will handle the actual path from `OnClick` handler, but it won't allow you to avoid actual traversing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create an anonymous event handler which will capture any relevant data and pass it to a different method:

```
var menuItem = new MenuItem(
    "Create New Folder",
    // the following lambda will capture the `e` parameter
    (sender, args) => DoSomething(e.Node, "stuff just happened"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to create your own custom MenuItem like this :

```
public class CustomMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public TreeNode SelectedTreeNode { get; set; }

    public CustomMenuItem(string text, EventHandler onClick, TreeNode treeNode) : base(text, onClick)
    {
        SelectedTreeNode = treeNode;
    }
}
```

So instead of creating your menuitem like you do here :

```
cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Create New Folder",CreateNewFolder_Click));
```

Yo do :

```
cm.MenuItems.Add(new CustomMenuItem("Create New Folder", CreateNewFolder_Click, e.Node));
```

Then you will get your TreeNode in your method like this :

```
private void CreateNewFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomMenuItem customMenuItem = sender as CustomMenuItem;
    MessageBox.Show(customMenuItem.SelectedTreeNode.FullPath);
}
```